# Aerospike Kubernetes operator installing error in EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, aerospike, cert-manager

**strong text**Till the cert-manager every pods working good as followed by aerospike docs. But while installing the operator the operator pods get crash loop backoff.

Installing operator using:

```
git clone https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-kubernetes-operator.git
git checkout 2.5.0
cd aerospike-kubernetes-operator/helm-charts
helm install aerospike-kubernetes-operator ./aerospike-kubernetes-operator --set replicas=3
```

Pods running:

```
PS C:\Users\B.Jimmy\aerospike-kubernetes-operator-1.0.0> kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE      NAME                                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
cert-manager   cert-manager-576c79cb45-xkr88                    1/1     Running            0                4h41m
cert-manager   cert-manager-cainjector-664f76bc59-4b5kz         1/1     Running            0                4h41m
cert-manager   cert-manager-webhook-5d4fd5cb7f-f96qx            1/1     Running            0                4h41m
default        aerospike-kubernetes-operator-7bbb8745c8-86884   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   36 (59s ago)     159m
default        aerospike-kubernetes-operator-7bbb8745c8-jzkww   1/2     Error              36 (5m14s ago)   159m
kube-system    aws-node-7b4nb                                   1/1     Running            0                21h
kube-system    aws-node-llnzh                                   1/1     Running            0                21h
kube-system    coredns-6c97f4f789-fhnq6                         1/1     Running            0                21h
kube-system    coredns-6c97f4f789-wmcdm                         1/1     Running            0                21h
kube-system    kube-proxy-5gwld                                 1/1     Running            0                21h
kube-system    kube-proxy-z2nwk                                 1/1     Running            0                21h
olm            catalog-operator-56db4cd676-hln6h                1/1     Running            0                21h
olm            olm-operator-5b8f867598-7h9z6                    1/1     Running            0                21h
olm            operatorhubio-catalog-bd8rq                      1/1     Running            0                178m
olm            packageserver-7cbbc9c85f-jms5f                   1/1     Running            0                21h
olm            packageserver-7cbbc9c85f-z45jg                   1/1     Running            0                21h
```

Crashing Pod Log:

```
PS C:\Users\B.Jimmy\aerospike-kubernetes-operator-1.0.0> kubectl logs -f aerospike-kubernetes-operator-7bbb8745c8-86884
Defaulted container "manager" out of: manager, kube-rbac-proxy
flag provided but not defined: -config
Usage of /manager:
  -health-probe-bind-address string
        The address the probe endpoint binds to. (default ":8081")
  -kubeconfig string
        Paths to a kubeconfig. Only required if out-of-cluster.
  -leader-elect
        Enable leader election for controller manager. Enabling this will ensure there is only one active controller manager.
  -metrics-bind-address string
        The address the metric endpoint binds to. (default ":8080")
  -zap-devel
        Development Mode defaults(encoder=consoleEncoder,logLevel=Debug,stackTraceLevel=Warn). Production Mode defaults(encoder=jsonEncoder,logLevel=Info,stackTraceLevel=Error) (default true)
  -zap-encoder value
        Zap log encoding (one of 'json' or 'console')
  -zap-log-level value
        Zap Level to configure the verbosity of logging. Can be one of 'debug', 'info', 'error', or any integer value > 0 which corresponds to custom debug levels of increasing verbosity
  -zap-stacktrace-level value
        Zap Level at and above which stacktraces are captured (one of 'info', 'error', 'panic').
```

> Do I need to configure nginx ingress after installing cert-manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can recreate a similar behavior by following the steps you provided. I think there may be an accidental mistype with those steps in regards to the branch checkout so its attempting to use the `master` branch instead of `2.5.0`

The steps should be:

```
git clone https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-kubernetes-operator.git
cd aerospike-kubernetes-operator/helm-charts
git checkout 2.5.0
helm install aerospike-kubernetes-operator ./aerospike-kubernetes-operator --set replicas=3
```

notice the `cd` and `git checkout` commands flipped

**NOTE: You may need to uninstall the current helm chart first before reinstalling **

Example:

```
helm uninstall aerospike-kubernetes-operator
```

As a side note: I see you also have OLM namespaces already and may benefit using the OLM installation for AKO found here: https://docs.aerospike.com/cloud/kubernetes/operator/install-operator-operatorhub

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hi @Colton, Thanks for your suggestion. I tried with different version installation with cloning the exact version branch code from github and got succeded installing of aerospike operator :)